# Copy file crashes terminal while sshfs disconnects

Tags: linux, sshfs

I have a perl script that runs in the background and copies files from my local system to a remote device connected through sshfs. The problem is that if the connection fails while the script is copying a file, the script completely freezes. If the connection fails anywhere else in the script, the script does not freeze. The script also cannot be killed by a kill or kill -9 command. It has become a zombie process.

Anyone who came across the same problem and has a potential solution?
I've tried creating a parent script that would start a new instance of the script (using the screen command, so it would run in a whole other process), but that script also freezes :(

Some pseudo code:

```
while (1) {
    if (!device is mounted) {
        sleep 1;
        next;
    }
    // calculate files to copy
    if (files to copy) {
        copy_files();
    }
}

copy_files {
    foreach my $file (@files) {
        if (!device is mounted) {
            return;
        }
        // copy this file
    }
}
```

Edit:
I have some more information about the problem. It is not related to perl at all and can be reproduced very easily. All you need is 3 terminals.

1. Open a terminal and sshfs your device to a mountpoint (lets say this mountpoint is /home/user/mountpoint).
2. Open a second terminal with the next command:

   while true; do mountpoint /home/user/mountpoint; sleep 1; done

   This will print *is (not) a mountpoint* every second.
3. Open a third terminal with which you copy a large file to your mountpoint:

   cp /home/user/very_big_file /home/user/mountpoint
4. Now disconnect your device from the internet (eg by turning off the wifi).

Result is that now terminal 2 and 3 are frozen. Umounting and remounting the device does not fix the problem. However if you shut down the connection gracefully (eg with fusermount -uz /home/user/mountpoint) instead of a hard disconnect, neither process crashes. If you do a disconnect without copying a file, the mountpoint command will print 'is a not mountpoint' followed by 'is a mountpoint' when the device is connected again, so it does not crash. It seems like the combination of network interruption and copying a file over ssh that causes some processes to hang.

Comment: This is surely about details; thanks for pseudo code but that doesn't say much.  For one: how are files copied?  Then, why not perform copying in a fork, and if the child process gets unresponsive whack that process and carry on?  Or, put copying code in a separate program and run it via a good library that allows to check and manage its jobs (`IPC::Run` for instance)

Comment: (none of this handles the "freeze"-ing problem but then you said nothing about it...)

Comment: Often, when paring your code down to an [mcve] you make a discovery that solves the problem for you. As mentioned above, readers need code with details. Make the smallest program you can that demonstrates the problem. AND/OR provide more details about how and when the program freezes. Are you trying to parallel copy files to your remote machine? If so, does changing it to one-at-a-time change the situation? Good luck.

Comment: Btw, as convenient as it may be, `sshfs` is at this time practically [abandoned](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs#this-project-is-orphaned) as far as a I know?  (With a list of known problems.)

Comment: I've added more information to the post. It is unrelated to perl. @zdim I will try IPC::Run later and will let you know if it solves the issue. Do you have any good alternatives to sshfs?

Comment: @shelter It's one file at a time.

Comment: "_I've added more information to the post_"  -- That does help; you do have a problem there.  Could check for connection and copy, but that's a race condition.  Perhaps a `fork` would help because you can ignore that subprocess if it gets locked out (and clean up later), but that is messy.  (And I don't know from where you run the program -- does that terminal itself go away when connection disappears?) Anything I can think of is way too complicated.

Comment: "_good alternatives to sshfs?_"  -- Why do you need `sshfs`? I've seen people use it for convenience, or when they need their whole environments from one host to work on another.  There are many ways to use other hosts,  perhaps not as convenient but more predictable.  What do you need to do?

Comment: I'm running this script on a remote machine (using ssh), the terminal does not close or disconnects. I just want to copy files to my phone through a script. What I need to be able to do is: copy a file, delete a file, move a file, create/delete a folder and read the contents of a folder.

Comment: OK, I see.  I'd say: 1) If the controlling script doesn't fail then a `fork` (or another script driven by a library like `IPC::Run`) should work -- if it gets unresponsive discard it, keep checking for connection, run again  2) Can do all that with plain `ssh`/`scp`.  (I don't see that you'd _need_ `sshfs` for that.) All those things, one by one -- or, write a separate script to automate those actions, transfer it via `scp` and run it via `ssh`.  That short-and-simple script can even be written dynamically, if your main program knows exactly what to do only at runtime

Comment: Btw, consider `rsync` (uses `ssh`) instead of `scp`.  The only downside: many many options and some can be subtle and picky.  But once you figured it out it's awesome.   (I do my backups with it...)

Comment: Another question.  So you are on "box1" and `ssh` to "box2" and in that `ssh` command run the main program (which lives on box2 I presume).  Correct?  Now, in that program you want to copy files ... from where to where -- which "box" to which "box'?  Delete, move, manipulate folders ... where?  On which box?  (Yet another? Or a folder (mount point) where your cell phone disk is mounted?)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've switched to scp. It doesn't have the same problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in sshfs. It is outdated.
Better is just to use scp.